# How to obtain a plain text Django error page

Tags: python, django, http

During development, I am running Django in Debug mode and I am posting data to my application using a text mode application. Ideally, I need to receive a plain text response when I get an http error code 500 so I don't have to look for the real error inside all that HTML and Javascript.

Is it possible to obtain a Django 500 Internal Server Error as plain text?

Comment: simao, can you reconsider which answer is the accepted one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21498065 Seems like the correct & simple way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think to write a middleware, because otherwise the exception isn't available in the 500.html

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

```
class ProcessExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        t = Template("500 Error: {{ exception }}")
        response_html = t.render(Context({'exception' : exception }))

        response = http.HttpResponse(response_html)
        response.status_code = 500
        return response
```

Comment: This works, thanks.
The problem now is to access the stack trace, because "exception" is just a regular Exception object.

Comment: Congrats! Look into `sys.exc_info()` to get access to the traceback. I suggest looking directly at the django code that does the traceback formatting normally in `django.core.handlers.base` to implement your own version.

Comment: @Dmitry's answer is better, IMHO.

Answer (score 22):

If you are looking for a way to get a plain text error page when using `curl`, you
need to add the HTTP header `X-Requested-With` with value `XMLHttpRequest`, e.g.

```
curl -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' http://example.com/some/url/
```

Explanation: this is because Django uses the `is_ajax` method to determine whether or not to return as plain text or as HTML. `is_ajax` in turn looks at `X-Requested-With`.

---

#### Update

Since django version 3.1, error reporting ignores the `X-Requested-With` header. Instead, set the `Accept` header on the request to any valid value which *does not* include the `text/html` mime type.

e.g.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' http://example.comp/some/url
```

Comment: In 2020, use the 'Accept' header with some value that _doesn't_ include 'text/html'

Answer (score 8):

There's a setting [DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions) which will force Django not to wrap the exceptions, so you can see them, e.g. in devserver logs.

Comment: That link no longer works. Instead, you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions

Comment: If you make a request to the Django server, it still returns the 500 error wrapped in HTML rather than as plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

This is an improvement on Yuji's answer, which provides a stacktrace, more instructions (for us django newbies) and is simpler.

Put this code in a file somewhere in your application, e.g. `PROJECT_ROOT/MAIN_APP/middleware/exceptions.py`, and make sure you have an empty `__init__.py` in the same directory.

```
import traceback
from django.http import HttpResponse

class PlainExceptionsMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        return HttpResponse(traceback.format_exc(exception), content_type="text/plain", status=500)
```

Now edit your `settings.py` and find `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (`. Add another entry so it is like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # (all the previous entries)

    # Plain text exception pages.
    'MAIN_APP.middleware.exceptions.PlainExceptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Restart django and you are good to go!

## User-agent aware formatting.

If you're like me and developing an app and a website both backed by django, you probably want to show plain text error pages to the app, and the nice formatted ones to the browser. A simple way to to that is to check the user agent:

```
import traceback
from django.http import HttpResponse

class PlainExceptionsMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if "HTTP_USER_AGENT" in request.META and "chrome" in request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].lower():
            return
        return HttpResponse(traceback.format_exc(exception), content_type="text/plain", status=500)
```

Comment: Support for MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES was removed in Django 2.0.

Comment: For a middleware class nowadays, you need to add the method `def __init__(self, get_response): self.get_response = get_response`

Comment: This middleware still returns HTML. It seems that if you even call `traceback.format_exc(exception)`, the rest of `process_exception` doesn't run, so the exception is returned in HTML as usual.

Comment: It works fine if you simply do `traceback.format_exc()`, instead of passing in `exception`

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Timmmm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730922/5139284), I had to make several modifications for it to work in Django 3.1:

Create a file somewhere in your application, such as `YOUR_APP_NAME/middleware/exceptions.py` and paste the following code:

```py
import traceback
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest

class PlainExceptionsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request: HttpRequest, exception: Exception):
        if "HTTP_USER_AGENT" in request.META and "chrome" in request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].lower():
            return
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return HttpResponse(repr(exception), content_type="text/plain", status=500)
```

It is not necessary to create an `__init__.py` file in the `middleware` folder.

In `settings.py`, add the following item to the end of the MIDDLEWARE variable, so that it looks like:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'YOUR_APP_NAME.middleware.exceptions.PlainExceptionsMiddleware'
]
```

Now, if "HTTP_USER_AGENT" and "chrome" are in the request header, this middleware doesn't do anything, so Django returns an HTML response as usual. Otherwise, it returns a plain-text representation of the error as a response (e.g., `ValueError("Field 'id' expected a number but got 'undefined'.")`) and prints out the traceback to the Django console, as Django normally would. Of course, you can instead return the full traceback as your response.