# Returning Django exceptions in plain text

Tags: django, debugging, error-handling

Errors caught by Django in DEBUG mode are returned in HTML-formatted code for browser display. I'd like to have those errors display in plain text (or JSON) instead. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So you want to display a custom error, but only when DEBUG = True?

Comment: If ADMINS is set and the email settings are filled in, Djano will send admins an email with the errors in plaintext when DEBUG is off. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports

Docs also says "Server error emails are sent using the logging framework, so you can customize this behavior by customizing your logging configuration" so you can probably dump them to a file that way.

From your question, I think you require the plaintext errors to appear in a browser, though.

Comment: @sandinmyjoints the e-mail option is nice, but in this case Django is being used as an API and I want the front-end developer to be able to identify the errors right away as opposed to waiting for an e-mail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain a plain text Django error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921164/how-to-obtain-a-plain-text-django-error-page)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could modify the templates found in this file: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/debug.py

Change `TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE`, `TECHNICAL_404_TEMPLATE`, and `EMPTY_URLCONF_TEMPLATE` to display plaintext.

Comment: This looks promising, but this would require patching some of the Django source code, there's got to be a way to do this at the project level....

Comment: There _could_ be, but I think likely there is not. Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/) are pretty comprehensive, and they don't mention something like that. Forking Django from [github](https://github.com/django/django) doesn't have to be a huge deal, as you can continue to upgrade by merging, and you wouldn't be making massive changes. Just my $0.02! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution, but perhaps throwing django-sentry into the mix would allow you to do something more with the errors reported? Im still new to it myself.