# Disable Django exception formatting

Tags: python, django, exception

I'm calling Django from within another application.

While debugging, if a Django exception occurs, the (html) response body is being picked up and then wrapped in an exception generated in the calling app.

This makes it a real pain to determine what the problem was as I need to wade through CSS, Html, Js, etc.

Is there any way to get Django to only output an exception message and a stack trace as plain text?

[image]

Comment: There's a textarea w/ plaintext traceback in django error page. However I think you would like to have debug turned off, later on production machine and django will not expose this error page, just laconic information that exception happened. Solution: you can try to write middleware class, which will catch an exception and then you can do with it whatever you want (send somewhere via socket, write to file, output as a plain text...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain a plain text Django error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921164/how-to-obtain-a-plain-text-django-error-page)

Comment: @mic Thanks for the link, but the answer below resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own exception-handling middleware class. See the documentation for the [`process_exception` middleware method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception):

> `process_exception(self, request, exception)`
>
> `request` is an `HttpRequest` object. `exception` is an `Exception` object raised by the view function.
>
> Django calls `process_exception()` when a view raises an exception. `process_exception()` should return either `None` or an `HttpResponse` object. If it returns an `HttpResponse` object, the response will be returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks in.

So I think you need to write something like this:

```
import traceback
from django.http import HttpResponse

class PlainTextExceptionMiddleware(object):
     def process_exception(self, request, exception):
         return HttpResponse(traceback.format_exc(), "text/plain")
```

and then add the class to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: Sounds like a nice solution - if I can't get @Igor's suggestion working, I'll give it a spin. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` in your settings:

```
If set to True, Django’s normal exception handling of view functions
will be suppressed, and exceptions will propagate upwards. This 
can be useful for some test setups, and should never be used on a live site.
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions)

Comment: That looks promising but doesn't seem to be habing any effect. I'll do some reading