# Django: ascii Traceback from Debug Page (HTML)

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I write integration tests, which go through the whole HTTP stack:

- requests library connects to http server
- http server routes request to the django application
- django application processes the request

If there is an uncaught exception in the django application I get the HTML debug page, since settings.DEBUG is True.

In most cases I like this page, but here want to have a simple ascii traceback which can I can show in our Continuous Application tool (Jenkins).

How to get an ascii traceback if I test my application with an url client library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain a plain text Django error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921164/how-to-obtain-a-plain-text-django-error-page)

Answer (score 2):

Rendering of this page with `DEBUG=True` is done in `BaseHandler`. which calls `django.views.debug.technical_500_response` view for all uncaught exceptions. But when `DEBUG=False` another view is called `django.views.defaults.server_error`. So you have 2 options

1. write custom middleware that will catch all uncaught exceptions and render them as plain text
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception
2. Create separate setting file for jenkinks set here `DEBUG=False` and in your `urls.py` for `if jenkins_env` set `handler500=custom_technical_500_response`
   which will render your exceptions the way you need
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#http-internal-server-error-view and 
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#handler500